# Xcode 6 Documentation: How to increase font size

Tags: xcode, xcode6

In Xcode, I go to the Help menu and select Xcode Overview documentation. I find the font quite small. I would like to increase the font size. How do I do that? Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

Just got an answer from Apple forum

"hold the command key and press +"